# Is there a way to specify font-stretch to custom font in jsPDF?

Tags: html, css, fonts, jspdf

I am using [**jsPDF**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) to generate PDF and I need to load a custom font with multiple `font-stretch` values (normal, condensed and expanded) from a Font Family I defined which supports it.

However, I don't see how I can specify that `font-stretch` property when loading the font.

This is how I declare my Font Family in CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-normal.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-stretch: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-condensed.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-stretch: condensed;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-expanded.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-stretch: expanded;
}
```

This is how I load the three custom fonts into jsPDF

*Here, in line 5 is where I think I should declare the condensed / expanded variations, but the other possible values I am aware of are Italic, Bold and their combinations*

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-normal.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-normal.ttf', 'Bahnschrift', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-condensed.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-condensed.ttf', 'Bahnschrift', 'normal');   // I think I should be able to set condensed here
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-expanded.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-expanded.ttf', 'Bahnschrift', 'normal');   // I think I should be able to set expanded here
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

Finally, I use the font like this

```
const font = `normal normal 400 16px Bahnschrift`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

```
const font = `condensed normal 400 16px Bahnschrift`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

```
const font = `expanded normal 400 16px Bahnschrift`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

Could anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution and I am posting it here in case someone else is struggling with this.

I declared different font families for each variation, so there is no need to specify the variation as a property, but just use the corresponding font family.

My code looks like this now

Here are my font families declarations

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift-normal;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-normal.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift-condensed;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-condensed.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift-expanded;
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Bahnschrift/bahnschrift-expanded.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Then I load fonts into jsPDF like this

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-normal.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-normal.ttf', 'Bahnschrift-normal', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-condensed.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-condensed.ttf', 'Bahnschrift-condensed', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = "<base64 font file>"
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Bahnschrift-expanded.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Bahnschrift-expanded.ttf', 'Bahnschrift-expanded', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

And then I use the fonts like this

```
const font = `normal normal 400 16px Bahnschrift-normal`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

```
const font = `normal normal 400 16px Bahnschrift-condensed`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

```
const font = `normal normal 400 16px Bahnschrift-expanded`;
await document.fonts.load(font);
pdf.font = font;
```

As a side note, do not use numbers in font family names, jsPDF does not load them as expected. I encountered this problem in my troubleshooting trip and spent a lot of time with it.

I hope this helps someone.